# Unity app problem with Google Sign-in after upload to Google Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After configuring Google Sign-in for my Unity application, I created an APK file, which I successfully installed on an Android device without any issues. However, upon uploading the application to Google Play, I noticed that the Google Sign-in feature was no longer functioning properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Google;
using UnityEditor;

public class StartScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text statusLoginPanel;
    public Text descriptionLoginPanel;
    public Text statusGamePanel;
    public Text descriptionGamePanel;
    public Text versionN;
    public GameObject panelLogin;
    public GameObject panelGame;
    private bool loginCorrect;
    //Firebase Auth
    protected Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    protected Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;

    protected string GoogleWebAPI;
    private GoogleSignInConfiguration configuration;

    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

    private void Awake()
    {
        GoogleWebAPI = "622458959424-ovojku5XXX";
        configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
        {
            WebClientId = GoogleWebAPI,
            RequestIdToken = true
        };
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        panelLogin.SetActive(true);
        panelGame.SetActive(false);
        versionN.text = "v. " + Application.version + " b. 7";
        descriptionLoginPanel.text = "";
        descriptionGamePanel.text = "";
        statusGamePanel.text = "";
        statusLoginPanel.text = "";
        initFrebase();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void initFrebase()
    {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    }

    void GoogleSignInClick()
    {
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        //GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
    }

    void OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
    {
        
        if(task.IsFaulted)
        {
            descriptionLoginPanel.text = task.Exception.ToString();
            statusLoginPanel.text = "Google Fault";
        }
        else if(task.IsCanceled)
        {
            descriptionLoginPanel.text = task.Exception.ToString();
            statusLoginPanel.text = "Google Canceled";
        }
        else
        {
            statusLoginPanel.text = "Google Sign-in successful";
        }
    }
    public void pressButton()
    {
        descriptionLoginPanel.text = "";
        descriptionGamePanel.text = "";
        statusGamePanel.text = "";
        statusLoginPanel.text = "";
        loginTest2();
    }

    protected void loginTest2()
    {
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
    }

    public void pressButtonLogout() { loginTest3(); }

    protected void loginTest3()
    {
        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();
        statusLoginPanel.text = "Succesfully Loged out";
        panelLogin.SetActive(true);
        panelGame.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Installed from APK:
[APK front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNfPF.jpg)

After uploading it to Google Play...:
[Google Play front page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FZRQ.jpg)

Google Play has activated service with web server credentials:
[Web server credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRsa.png)

The result remained the same.